# How to maintain react component state when goback from router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react components let say A and B. When A is shown on the page, user changes something on that page which cause some states changed inside A. Then user click a button which navigate to B by `router.push('/b')`. Then user click a back a back button and navigate the page to A which is done by `router.goBack()`. Now the current URL is A but the previously updated states are gone. How can I maintain the state when user go back to A?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to enable `BrowserHistory` on your router by intializing it like that : `<Router history={new BrowserHistory}>`.

Before that, you should require `BrowserHistory from 'react-router/lib/BrowserHistory'`

I hope that helps !

```
 var BrowserHistory = require('react-router/lib/BrowserHistory').default;

var App = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
    return (
        <div>xxx</div>
    );
  }
});

React.render((
<Router history={BrowserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
), document.body);
```

Another way you can try is this,

```
this.context.router.goBack()
```

No navigation mixin required!

**EDIT: Update with React v15 and ReactRouter v3.0.0 (Aug 20th, 2016):**

```
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

var BackButton = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <button
        className="button icon-left"
        onClick={browserHistory.goBack}>
        Back
      </button>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: if the solution works for you, mark it as a right answer so that others can get help from it.

Comment: I know browser history can help here. However my react app is loaded in android webview which doesn't support browser history.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to manage the state for whole application. Hence, you need to use redux for this purpose. Its not within my scope to say whole lot about redux in here but you can use redux and react-redux to manage such state by installing them from npm. Thanks

Comment: I am using redux but I think it is quite complex if I put a lot state in redux store. Moreover, these states are just temp states which should not exist in redux store after finish using it.